# Filling in Null Data Gaps in Raster Image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, null

I am looking to fill in small gaps of no data/null values in my raster image within ArcMap.

Are there any good techniques to approach this, while also not degrading the image in the process?

[image: Image with Null Values]

Answer (score 2):

Fill in Arcmap helps to remove imperfections in surface raster Data. 
Go to Arc Toolbox, Spatial Analyst Tools ,Hydrology , Fill. This Fill will use the surrounding cell values to interpolate for the null value in the surface raster.